# Use Jquery On One Page Website withe mouse Wheel scroll

Tags: jquery

I use mouseWheel control Image moving,

use this function get Top position:

```
$(this).scrollTop();
```

and let image moving with this function :

```
$("‪#‎img‬").css({top:currentoffset});
```

I have a problem,

I use IE browser , the visual effect is very runout.

use google browser the image moving  is Normal. How can I solve this problem on IE browser?

Comment: Please place some code on Fiddle, whatsoever you have achieved so far.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the CSS value of the image's `top` to a value, it changes instantly.  Depending on how the browser is configured, the amount of scrolling done by the mousewheel at any point can vary.  Try animating the change in position to reduce jumpiness.

For example:

```
$('#img').animate({
  top: currentoffset
}, 250);
```

The 250 means 1/4 of a second, so adjust accordingly (may need to go smaller).

Comment: Jeremy Miller

I want visual effect is real time (google browser can real time),

I use animate() function , reduce jumpiness on ie now.

so difference Between IE and google browser on visual effect.

This phenomenon is normal?

Comment: Think of it as smooth scrolling versus stepped scrolling.  It's not so much the browser, per se, but the various settings on the system (my mouse allows me to activate smooth scrolling, for example).  So, if that is not active, then it jumps a step (which can be configured by the end user).  You'll want it to catch up, then either by jumping (you don't like this) or be animating to the position.  That's the best I can help with what you've provided.